# deployed but context failed to start with tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web.xml

Issue is when I using any filter or listener in my web xml, the following error will be displayed.

[image]

and my web.xml

[image]

Here is my config code:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>log4j</groupId> 
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

what can I do for this to be fixed?

Comment: check catalina.out and paste the stacktrace if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: hi @SMA im getting this error as well but I have configured log4j in my classpath : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Comment: do you have slf4j*.jar in your classpath. You are missing that jar in your classpath.

Comment: here is my config `code`<dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
     </dependency>`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This application previously was with tomcat7 plugin (tomcat7-maven-plugin) that will be used.The Tomcat7 plugin will download the Tomcat7 to the my machine, and once the Maven generate the war artifact, will deploy it to a Tomcat7 instance started by the plugin itself.

my configurations before

```
<configuration>
          <port>8080</port>
          <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
          <additionalConfigFilesDir>${basedir}/src/main/tomcat/conf</additionalConfigFilesDir>
          <systemProperties>
              <log4j.configuration>file:./src/main/tomcat/conf/log4j.xml</log4j.configuration>
          </systemProperties>
</configuration>
     <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.16</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.14</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

and later I changed it to this

```
 <configuration>
              <url>http://localhost:8099/manager/text</url>
              <server>TomcatServer</server>
              <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
              <additionalConfigFilesDir>${basedir}/src/main/tomcat/conf</additionalConfigFilesDir>
              <systemProperties>
                  <log4j.configuration>file:./src/main/tomcat/conf/log4j.xml</log4j.configuration>
              </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
```

so after those changes, the library scopes previously I had(provided) should be changed accordingly in pom.xml.After made that changes context started successfully.